# Brown noise on cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How can I create a brown noise  generator using Cocoa?

BTW Brown noise is similar to pink and white noise and has nothing to do with "The brown note" or anything silly.  See http://www.mediacollege.com/audio/noise/brown-noise.html

Comment: You could look into http://musickit.sourceforge.net/MusicKitConcepts/

Comment: In all seriousness, I think he was referring to this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_noise.

Comment: Brown noise is like white and pink noise. It's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: This should not have been closed, it is a legitimate question. There's no need to be so authoritarian. He wants to create a brown noise generator using Cocoa.

Comment: @dreamlax, @Joshua That's exactly what I'm trying to do, and I have no idea why it was considered a joke by some.

Comment: @Sam Thank, ill check the musickit.

Comment: That you even had to specify the difference between noise and note is embarrassing. And not for you. :-)

Comment: @Joshua I had no idea what this "brown note" was (had to google for it). At least I now understand the initial reaction: such a mac application could wreak havoc on Apple's business. ;-)

Comment: Typically bathroom-themed American humor, unfortunately. Such an app would sure beat the hell out of the myriad fart apps though... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I saw some open source white noise Core Audio audio units around the web but I can't find them. In any case I'd start there since the basics are the same. I think Brown noise is just a few differently set parameters / ranges.

MusicKit might certainly work but Core Audio is part of the OS and likely a lot more CPU-friendly because of that.